# Joomla not showing page names in url bar

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

So for some reason Joomla is not showing the name of a page on my website.

For example:

My webpage is www.meteordesign.nl and if I go to contact page the url doesn't change to www.meteordesign.nl/contact. It stays on www.meteordesign.nl.

Does anyone know how I can fix this irritating problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check `Global Configuration` and check `SEO` setting and turn on `Search Engine Friendly URLs` into `YES`

[Here Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPfKZ.png)

Comment: @chainboost can you attach screenshot of your Global-setting page?

Comment: @chainboost is it happen all pages or few pages? 
Did you clear your cache?

plase refer this

 [link 1] ( https://docs.joomla.org/Common_problems_when_enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_(SEF)_URLs )

[link 2] ( https://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_(SEF)_URLs )

Comment: @chainboost Addition to `little bunny`, you should rename your `htaccess.txt` file to `.htaccess` and turn `Use URL Rewriting` in your `Global Configuration` to `Yes` this will give you better sef url. **Lastly, If your issue is fixed now, mark this answer correct & give some credits to `little bunny`**

Comment: @littlebunny Will do later today, sorry have been busy!

Comment: @littlebuny It's working now! Seems it was the cache on my side. Feel so stupid right now. Thnx for helping and again sorry for the later answer!

Comment: @chainboost you are welcome.don't forget vote me.. :)